# How to display latex or mathematical equation in a android compose application?

Tags: latex, android-jetpack-compose, mathematical-expressions

I want to build a android application based on jet pack compose which can display math equations or latex.

I have checked internet and found many libraries but all are for xml and not for compose and also they are outdated and do not work for xml even. I am trying to find a library which work for compose or at the worst case for xml and need bare minimum code snippets for gradle, main activity Kotlin, compose (or xml) which works.

Answer (score 1):

Using [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) and [WebViews](https://google.github.io/accompanist/web/), you need to create a file `main/assets/latex_render.html`, with the following content (most of it taken from [KaTeX docs](https://katex.org/docs/browser#starter-template)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- KaTeX requires the use of the HTML5 doctype. Without it, KaTeX may not render properly -->
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.9/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-n8MVd4RsNIU0tAv4ct0nTaAbDJwPJzDEaqSD1odI+WdtXRGWt2kTvGFasHpSy3SV" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.9/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-XjKyOOlGwcjNTAIQHIpgOno0Hl1YQqzUOEleOLALmuqehneUG+vnGctmUb0ZY0l8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.9/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-+VBxd3r6XgURycqtZ117nYw44OOcIax56Z4dCRWbxyPt0Koah1uHoK0o4+/RRE05" crossorigin="anonymous"
            onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
</head>
<body style="
background-color:transparent;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
">

<p id="ident" style="color: white"></p>

<script>
    function addBody(latexString) {
        katex.render(latexString, document.getElementById('ident'), {
            throwOnError: false
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here, you wait for the `addBody` function to execute and then the LaTeX expression will be displayed.

The styling applied to the `body` tag is mostly for page arrangement, with the exception of `background-color: transparent`, which I've found to be needed to stop the flickering of the WebView when it's first created.

Now, for the Android Compose part, you will need to add the following dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```java
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-webview:0.31.3-beta")
```

Then, you can create a wrapper component over the WebView, something simple like this should suffice:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun LaTeXView(latex: String) {

    var webView: WebView? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

    val state = rememberWebViewState("file:///android_asset/latex_render.html")

    if (state.loadingState is LoadingState.Finished) {
        webView?.loadUrl("javascript:addBody('${latex}')")
    }
    com.google.accompanist.web.WebView(
        state = state,
        modifier = Modifier,
        onCreated = {
            it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView = it
            it.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
            it.setBackgroundColor(0)
        }
    )
}
```

(inspired by the response to this [KaTeXView issue](https://github.com/judemanutd/KaTeXView/issues/11), which unfortunately didn't work for me as-is, but it was close enough)

You should be able now to just render your latex like this:

```kotlin
LaTeXView(latex = "\\\\sin(x) \\\\cdot \\\\cos(y) \\\\cdot \\\\sin(x \\\\cdot y)")
```

And it should render something like this (minus the gradient background):

[image: LaTeX rendered]

Comment: I have tried the above method. Good thing is the code is not crashing and running. But the major problem is it is not displaying anything i.e. instead of showing latex it is showing blank. I tried changing the setting to  throwOnError: true in  katex.render and got the following error:-[INFO:CONSOLE(23)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: katex is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/latex_render.html (23). please suggest what to do.

Comment: Can you try to add internet permission to your app, in AndroidManifest?


`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`


It's possible that the CDN's did not load since they require a connection

Comment: after adding internet permission in AndroidManifest the error message changed to - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')", source: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.9/dist/katex.min.js. But still no Latex is displaying. kindly suggest what to do. Further with this setup it seems that the user can only use my App when he has a internet connection and not offline. Is it so?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the cause of this error, if the HTML content is exactly as provided that error should not exist.
Here is a minified example that does only that, from a fresh Android Compose project
https://github.com/cristimc8/LatexDisplay  
Regarding the internet, you can further download those CDN resources and pack them into your `assets` and you won't need internet connection, but I haven't actually tried that yet

Comment: Thanks a lot. The display has started coming. The problem was my background was white, so font color white was not visible. I have also tried local JS files and it worked. But still has little issue with Latex. So far I am mostly using normal English text without any formula or special character. Sometimes it is becoming italic without any spaces between words. Also for long lines, there is no wrapping and the line is going outside the display. Can you please help me on these issues?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm caught up this period and I can't test suggestions, what I think regarding the wrapping is that you can play around the styling in the html file, specifically with CSS, if you can't figure it out before I can test it I'll circle back to this and I'll try to implement that. Regarding the characters, I don't know more than you, I think you'll find more help on the Katex documentation