How to display latex or mathematical equation without the need of internet in a android compose application?
I want to build a android application based on jet pack compose which can display math equations or latex.
I have checked internet and found many libraries but no library worked properly so how can I display math equations or latex? (without the need of internet, sorry for bad english )

Check out this. It might help with your problem

Related (with internet requirements): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77094252/how-to-display-latex-or-mathematical-equation-in-a-android-compose-application

This question is similar to: How to display latex or mathematical equation in a android compose application?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
